# Microservices - Access & Security understanding

Tags: security, external, microservices, internal

I am coming today because I am getting into the MicroServices architecture logic for a POC. The thing is that I am not sure to totally understand the logic of how to manage the security of these services.

The thing is, I would like to have a part of my app that could be usable without being connected, so some services can be called by anyone, let use A for that case. However, I would like some services to be called only if the user is connected, let use B for that case.

So, it means that I have an API (C) for my client that can access A & B where B can only being accessed through C, unlike A (which can be access by any HTTP request from anywhere).

About that, I am not sure to understand the logic of the security applied between a MicroServices architecture. In fact, I saw a couple of articles and a couple of stack-overflow exchanges about it which are mostly:

- DMZ logic
- White List IP access
- Internal services & External services

So, what is finally the best approach? Because using White List IP access, by example, would mean that my Database should be accessed through an API (D.A.L. logic) and I am wondering if it's the best approach. If I understand the "External" & "Internal" logic, it means that some services are public and the others aren't? If so, how is it organized, how does it works at the bottom?

Thanks for any example or explanation, feel free to ask me any extra details.

Thank in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The question is very broad, as authentication and authorization are big topics in themselves.

I will try to keep the answer short here. If you have time and resources, please take a look at using OAuth. They are the industry-standard way of providing auth and access to REST APIs.

You can define different access patterns and associate it with OAuth at the time of user login. The authentication can be a separate service and it just handles the case of which user has what privileges. It would be better here to not be service-specific here like user A can access API B and C. Instead be functionality driven, like user A is admin, user B is a privileged user, user C is a particular business user who has access to make payments, etc.

Now that you have OAuth implemented and have a way of associating users to their access controls, pass these as headers to your actual micro-service. In your API, just check if the user has the right token and access and continue. If not, error out with 422. Heck, if you use good libraries, you can even do it outside of your API code (using filters, etc.)

Now coming to the alternatives you looked at, all of them might work, but they will have cons. Example, whitelisted IP might mean that every time the IP of your client changes, you need to change the whitelist. Or make it wildcard match, which can expose other unwanted IPs as well if you are not careful. Internal vs external services can generally mean public vs private APIs. It means that some APIs are not even accessible in the public network and only those within the VPN or subnet can access. Comes with its own complexities and problems.

My two cents: strive for cleaner and common patterns that everyone is using.

Comment: Interesting answer, thank you :) Do you have any "common pattern" in mind I can take a look at?

Comment: The blog: https://www.cloudfoundry.org/blog/oauth-rest/ can be very useful. It talks about OAuth, roles, scopes and using these to authorise users to access resources